# Unity Toggle script

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this working script where I can hide and show gameobjects, but would like to modify it to only show one object at the time.

So when i start play, then Target 1 is shown and if i activate m_key2, then m_Target2 is shown and the others hidden and so on.
Only one visible m_Target at the time.

That way I can switch between 3 objects beeing shown in the middle of the screen.

Using just one key to toggle between showing the 3 objects would also work, but seems harder to program?

Is it possible?

```
{
[SerializeField] private KeyCode m_Key1 = KeyCode.G;
[SerializeField] private KeyCode m_Key2 = KeyCode.G;
[SerializeField] private KeyCode m_Key3 = KeyCode.G;
[SerializeField] private GameObject m_Target1;
[SerializeField] private GameObject m_Target2;
[SerializeField] private GameObject m_Target3;


void Start()
{
    
}
void Update()
{
    if (m_Target1 != null && Input.GetKeyDown(m_Key1))
        m_Target1.SetActive(!m_Target1.activeSelf);
    if(m_Target2 != null && Input.GetKeyDown(m_Key2))
        m_Target2.SetActive(!m_Target2.activeSelf);
    if(m_Target3 != null && Input.GetKeyDown(m_Key3))
        m_Target3.SetActive(!m_Target3.activeSelf);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, you can do that. There are several approaches:

1. Take your approach

   ```
    void Update(){
    if (m_Target1 != null && Input.GetKeyDown(m_Key1))
    {
        m_Target1.SetActive(true);
        m_Target2.SetActive(false);
        m_Target3.SetActive(false);
        // not reversing because we from what I understand you don't want to
        // toggle you just want to activate so always true
        // setting others to false so that when you press one the others turn off
    }
    else if(m_Target2 != null && Input.GetKeyDown(m_Key2))
    {
        m_Target1.SetActive(false);
        m_Target2.SetActive(true);
        m_Target3.SetActive(false);
    }
    else if(m_Target3 != null && Input.GetKeyDown(m_Key3))
    {
        m_Target1.SetActive(false);
        m_Target2.SetActive(false);
        m_Target3.SetActive(true);
    }}
   ```

That would work but... I wouldn't recommend that for several reasons:

1. it's long and goofy
2. it only works for a predefined amount of gameObjects

I think your suggestion with just one button (or two buttons if you wanna do left and right) is a better solution.
In that case, you can do the following:

```
public class Display : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializedField]
    private KeyCode left;
    [SerializedField]
    private KeyCode right;
    [SerializedField]
    private GameObject[] targets;

    private int index = 0;
    private int prevIndex = 0;

    public void Start() {
        for (int i = 0; i < targets.Length; i++)
                targets[i].SetActive(i == 0);
    // turning off all targets and turning on first
    }


    public void Update() {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(left)) {
            prevIndex = index;
            index += index + 1 < targets.Length ? 1 : -(targets.Length - 1);
            targets[index].SetActive(true);
            targets[prevIndex].SetActive(false);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(right)) {
            prevIndex = index;
            index -= index -1 < 0 ? -(targets.Length - 1) : 1;
            targets[index].SetActive(true);
            targets[prevIndex].SetActive(false);
        }
    // if left or right buttons are pressed
    // changing the index, turning off previous and turning on current
    }
```

What you see here is simple, define a list of objects, any number would work so whether you want to display 3 objects or 20 it doesn't matter. Define left and right buttons.

When you press the left button it will either go to the next object or if at the last object will come back to the first.
pressing the right one will either go to the previous or to the last if at the first one.

the for loop turns all the objects off except for the object who's selected.

(I haven't tested it I just quickly wrote it so if there are any problems please let me know)

Comment: The loop is highly inefficient, since it executes `targets.Length - 2` unnecessary operations. You should optimize this by simply updating the objects at the old and new index.

Comment: You are right, there is no reason to update them all when you can only update 2.
But I was working quickly, and the OP did not ask for optimization. However, I'll update a solution. Thank you

Comment: Whoops
I wrote SerializedField instead of SerializeField... I told you I didn't test it so just a slight spelling error I copy pasted

Comment: Its alle good, i figured it out and deleted serializedfield and turned private to public.

Works great, good stuff.

My thanks :)

Comment: The recommendation is changing SerializedField to SerializeField, that would work, and change it back to private... public fields are never recommended. But it would still work so your choice

Comment: Also, if you could mark it as an answer to help others who may encounter your problem see the solution quickly

Comment: OK, i will change it back....did not notice the spelling error myself :)

I dont have enough reputation to mark the great answer up :(

"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."